# Autorefresh of Javascript form refresh after data entry

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vbscript

I'm attempting to auto-fill out a web form via VBScript.  I can fill out the form fine, but when my script fills it out vs when I manually fill it out produces a different reaction from the form.  The form is supposed to calculate BMI based on my entry and ENABLE the save button, however, it only does this if I enter this data manually.  I need to trigger whatever function is causing this check for entry.  The problem is, I'm not finding any clues as to which function is doing this...

Here is the script I used to fill out the field:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")("txtWeight").value = "170"
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop
```

Here are examples of the form and element in both states when weight filled out programmatically and manually.  Notice save button in element disabled and BMI not calculated:

**PROGRAMMATICALLY**
[image: disabled]
[image: element_disabled]

Here is an example with it manually filled out calculating BMI and save button enabled (element not showing "disabled"):

**MANUALLY**

[image: enabled]
[image: element_enabled]

Here is complete HTML pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9iLJw8Dw

Or maybe I can force the firing of the save event?

```
return VHM.BioM.btnStMeasurementsSave_onclick()
```

I realize this may not be much to go on.  May be tough to get help on this since getting to this point on the site requires a login.  If this requires any info I didn't provide, let me know and I'll grab it.

Comment: Try to apply `.focus()` and/or `.blur()` methods for fields you are interacting with, it might be a handler assigned to one of these events, which does calculation and enables button.

Comment: I tried both of those per your suggestion and also threw in .select, but nothing triggered it.  If I hit "enter" on the keyboard it calculates and enables save, but I really don't want to use sendkeys.  What if I email you my login creds?  Actually, my full script logs in and fills this out...  Hit a road block with this issue, so haven't gotten further.

Comment: Nope - I'm wrong.  I applied your suggestion incorrectly.  I retried and had success.  I was using .focus AFTER I filled out field, once I applied focus prior, it worked.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply `.focus()` and/or `.blur()` methods for fields you are interacting with, it might be a handler assigned to one of these events, which does calculation and enables button.

Comment: So this worked only for a day    IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")("txtWeight").focus, now suddenly the form stopped responding to it.  Trying keydown, keyup, or keypress, but all erroring.  Found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events.  Applying like this:      IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")("txtWeight").keydown.  Getting "does support property or method" error.  How can I apply this without error to see if this works?  thx

Comment: Ok. Figured this out from reading up on it:     ie.document.dispatchevent("keypress").  It doesn't error, but also doesn't work...  It seems to kill the script without an error and without progressing.

Answer (score 1):

Using this method ultimately allowed me to achieve what I needed:  IE.document.getElementById("btnStMeasurementsSave").removeAttribute("disabled")

This removes the "disabled" attribute, which enables the save button and allows me to save.  Still giving credit to omega, as his solution initially solved the problem.